# Drupal : Uploading files in a multilingual context

Tags: drupal-7

I've got a question about uploading files to a node in Drupal 7, in a multilingual context.

I have a content type with a filefield, in  which a user can upload an image. How do i make that image be uploaded in the translations of this node too, when the form is submitted?

I tried in hook_node_submit, but as the file is not already saved, and hence has no fid, I'm a bit confused about he right way to proceed.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Solution found : use the synchronize translations module.